# How can I show a response from an api through Siri without opening the app?

Tags: ios, swift, chatbot, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I need to develop a Bot-like application with integration of `Siri` in iOS. By asking anything, `Siri` would accept my text and call an api by passing that text in as a parameter. To the response of that api, `Siri` should show me that text (or speak the responded text if possible), without opening the app.

Up to now, I am able to integrate Siri. Also I can get text from Siri and show it as an `IntentUI`. Now, if I call the api by passing that text and receive a response, how can I show the response (after I parse it) in Siri?

I use `INSendMessageIntentHandling` to handle messages. I found methods related to sending messages but I could not find any event that could process received responses (from anywhere).

**Is it possible to show responses using Siri without opening the app?**

Please let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: You need to implement a Siri Intent UI extension

Comment: I already did that. My question is can I use Siri as my app's interface by which user can interact with it without opening the app?

Comment: I don't understand your question - That is what the Siri Intent UI is - It is a way of displaying information in the Siri interface in response to a Siri Intent.  Are you referring to subsequent voice interactions as follow on from the original interaction?

Comment: My app has configured Siri with Message domain. If user asks anything to Siri and if it matches to that domain intent(of the app), the app will have the answer of that question. Now how the app will show/pass that answer to Siri and show it to the user? Does Siri IntentUI has capability to show the response after processing user's question? Does this make sense or still not?

Comment: Not really - That is what your Siri Intent UI extension does - handle the Intent and show a view controller that also conforms to `INUIHostedViewControlling`.  Take a look at the `SoupChefIntentsUI` target in Apple's SoupChef example

Comment: Ok I will look into it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can using sirikit to make custom intents and get parameters from user in ios 13.1
[See the demo apple showed at WWDC 2019](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/213/)
and [This is the project for the application they are demoing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/soup_chef_accelerating_app_interactions_with_shortcuts)